# How to setting up Strawberry Perl v5.30 ISAPI support for IIS

Tags: strawberry-perl

Recently installed Strawberry Perl v 5.30.1.1 64 bits and need to enable the ISAPI support into IIS to run pl scripts.

Was reading some articles and mention that the main dll file to doing it should be perlis.dll or PerlExXX.dll, unfortunately non of them are installed.

Any ideas where i can get the right library or which one i need to use in this version of perl ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the dll that i could't find, create a **Mapping Script** as follows:

[image]

And it is working fine now.